# How to make the Angular 2 know the process in service has got completed and raise a notification to the user in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

once i upload a file from angular 2 and call service to process the data in the sheet(spring batch does the processing of sheet) and once the processing is done have to notify the user that the process has got completed?

Comment: Are you processing file on server side or client side (ie you are building Electron app)?

Comment: processing file on server side

Answer (score 0):

Hold the response of that particular api till processing is done and then send the response, subscribe the response and notify the user accordingly. You can use HTML5 Notification API or if you want to notify the user via seperate api call then you can use service worker for that.